Set a column of a "list content type" required using REST in Power Automate
I'm looking to update a column that belongs to a list content type from optional to required using REST in Power Automate

I've been playing around with the SPFieldLink object collection,
but I do not find a way to update one of these objects using REST. I
get the error that a PATCH is not supported.
Adapting the SchemaXML for this column does not help either. The flow runs, there are no errors but nothing changes, my column does not go to required ...

Any ideas ?
This is part of the Power Automate flow that is started from a site design when a new site is provisioned.
Thank you,
Marc

can you add your query please, /_api/Web/Lists(guid'718ce222-882c-4bb5-b5b2-49cbaa0c9d11')/ContentTypes('0x01008C567DA24611480184F6AEBCEE04EC150079967B8E93FF804F982CF24F80CC44AE')/fields    sample here https://www.codesharepoint.com/rest-api/create-list-column-in-sharepoint-using-rest-api

Microsoft reference :Site Columns cannot be added to a content type using the REST service.
You can add a field to a site content type only if the field already exists on the parent content type.
You can add a field to a content type associated with a list only if the field already exists on the list. To add a completely new field to a list content type, you have to first add it to the list and then add it to the content type in a separate call to the REST service. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-visio/jj245869(v=office.15)

Power Automate Add Field To ContentType (reference Microsoft)
Note the following restrictions on adding a field (column) to a content type using the REST service:

Site Columns cannot be added to a content type using the REST
service. You can add a field to a site content type only if the field
already exists on the parent content type. You can add a field to a
content type associated with a list only if the field already exists
on the list. To add a completely new field to a list content type,
you have to first add it to the list and then add it to the content
type in a separate call to the REST service.

I added a sample on my blog
